# Multiple functions on single button with dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

how to provide multiple functions on single button in dojo , for example in slider the functionality of wipe in and wipe out must be on single button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement Wipe In/Wipe Out on Same button then Use [Dijit.form.ToggleButton](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/form/ToggleButton.html#dijit-form-togglebutton)

Other Wise if you want to add more functionality on one Button then use [Dijit.form.DropDownButton](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/form/DropDownButton.html#dijit-form-dropdownbutton)

Answer (score 0):

With [dojo/on](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/on.html) ([dojo.connect](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/connect.html) for <1.7) you can connect (and disconnect) as many functions as you want with events on domNodes (or widgets like button). See examples in these docs.

With these you can have variable defined as `this._isVisible` and toggle it on a click event on the button. Depending on the value of this var, you can decide what action to take.